# Itemstyle.xsl custom template

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I have a custom template that I use for a CQWP with announcements. I have it set to truncate the announcement at 750 characters, then show a link with the text [Full Announcement]. The issue is when an announcement is under 750 characters, it still shows the [Full Announcement] text. This is the code:

```
<xsl:template name="NewsAnnounStyle" match="Row[@Style='NewsAnnounStyle']" mode="itemstyle">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%;"> 
                    <tr style="background-color:#f6f6f6;"><td>
                        <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
                            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
                                <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <h3 style="font-weight:600;"><a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" style="color:#03478a;"><xsl:value-of select="@MyTitle"/></a></h3>         
                    </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>
                        <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
                            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
                                <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="substring(@MyDesc,1,750)" />
                    <xsl:if test="string-length(@MyDesc) &gt; 750">
            ... <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}">[Full Announcement]</a><br />
                             </xsl:if>
             </td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>           
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
```

Any ideas or guidance on how to have the [Full Announcements] only show when the announcement is over the 750 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<xsl:template name="NewsAnnounStyle" match="Row[@Style='NewsAnnounStyle']" mode="itemstyle">
    <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%;"> 
                    <tr style="background-color:#f6f6f6;">
                        <td>                        
                            <h3 style="font-weight:600;"><a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" style="color:#03478a;"><xsl:value-of select="@MyTitle"/></a></h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>                        
                            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="substring(@MyDesc,1,750)" />
                            <xsl:if test="string-length(@MyDesc) &gt; 750">
                                <span>...</span><a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}">[Full Announcement]</a><br />
                            </xsl:if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>           
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Amal, on shorter messages (<750) it has the link functioning now, but I'd like to have the ...[Full Announcement] text not show when the entire message is under 750 characters.